# WHERE colname LIKE '% %' OR colname LIKE '% % %' is returning rows with four words

Tags: sql

The following code is supposed to return rows where the City name is two or three words, however it also returns one with four words:

```sql
SELECT FirstName  ||' '|| LastName AS 'Full Name', City, Country, Email, Phone 
FROM customers  
WHERE City LIKE '% %' OR City LIKE '% % %';
```

[Output from Query]

[image: 1]

São José dos Campos appears if I use any of the three following codes:

```sql
LIKE '% %' 
 
LIKE '% % %'

LIKE '% % % %'
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

Other answers have explained why you're getting the answer you are -- the % wildcard with LIKE matches space characters, too -- but nobody has explained how to get what you want.

This will do it:

```
WHERE LENGTH(City) - LENGTH(REPLACE(City, ' ', '')) IN (1,2)
```

Syntax will vary somewhat by RDBMS (e.g., SQL Server calls it the LEN() function).

What this does is take the City field and replace each space with an empty string, which effectively removes that character. Then it subtracts the length from the length of the City with the spaces in it. That tells you how many spaces are in the City field. Then you just look for City fields that have the right number of spaces. 1 space means two words, etc.

Beware of leading or trailing spaces in some RDBMSs, as well as consecutive spaces.

If you need to use the LIKE operator, you can try something like this:

```
WHERE City LIKE '% %'
    AND City NOT LIKE '% % % %'
```

That will return where the City has at least one space, but less than three or more. Here, were using the fact that the 1 space pattern matches 2 spaces and the 3 space pattern matches 4 spaces to our advantage! You'll still want to beware of consecutive spaces and leading or trailing spaces. That may create unexpected results.

You'll have to test to see which option performs better in your system.

Some RDBMSs will give you expanded LIKE or full regex options, which can work even better than what's above.

Comment: The leading/trailing space problem can be easily solved by swapping out `City` for `LTRIM(RTRIM(City))` or `TRIM(City)` if your RDMS supports those

Answer (score 1):

The wildcard `%` matches *anything* including spaces. In particular a pattern like `'% %'` will match  `'São José dos Campos'` because:

- The first `%` matches `"São José dos"` and the second `%` matches `"Campos"`, or
- The first `%` matches `"São José"` and the second `%` matches `"dos Campos"`, or
- The first `%` matches `"São"` and the second `%` matches `"José dos Campos"`.

You don't mention which database you are using, but most database engines, now offer regular expression matching. With those you can precisely search for a very specific pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Symbol `%` means anything, including any number of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because "who can do the most, can do the least".

When using `LIKE` statement, `%` doesn't mean "a word" but "any pattern". Therefore, `% %` doesn't mean "two words separated by a space", but "any pattern, followed by a space, followed by any pattern". This actually makes you look for a string that contains at least one space.

And here's the cause: if a string that contains four spaces, it does contains two of them. So looking for this kind of string actually matches every string that contains two or more spaces, thus matching two, three, four or more words.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant

```
SELECT FirstName  ||' '|| LastName AS 'Full Name', City, Country, Email, Phone 
FROM customers  
WHERE City LIKE '% %' 
and City not LIKE '% % % %'
```

This means there needs to be at least one space but not 3 or more spaces.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, % is zero, one, or many characters, including spaces. So Cities with one, two or more spaces between those cities will match in LIKE "% %".

You can try this if you want cities that have only one or two spaces within:

WHERE City LIKE '% %' AND City NOT LIKE '% % % %';

But if there are cities that have 4 space or 5 space, you need to add another AND ... NOT LIKE for that.